# Question on a List of References for Improving Problem Solving Skills

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

I hope I am asking in the right place.

I have seen many people ask for guidance on MSE on how to improve problem solving skills.

I have replied to some requests in this area, but thought it is possible to do better.

I have researched and put together a better list of references to answer this question, which probably belongs in some community place for all to improve and add to.

Is it appropriate to post this list and ask for further inputs on the MSE?

If not, what is the desired approach (and saying we don't care for such a list or question is fine too).

Thanks -A

Comment: It would be nice to gather these references in one place. Post your research as an answer and ask for others' inputs in the question.